# Chrome: Autocomplete not working on particular input fields

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I've run into an issue in Chrome where autocomplete will remember the history of most input boxes, yet fails to save any history in one particular field.  Firefox was able to successfully save the history of that field, and Chrome still works with 99% of other fields.  Even fields elsewhere on the same form will have their history saved.  I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around what would be causing this picky issue.

Are there any workarounds for this?  Has anyone even experienced that problem before?

---

EDIT:  I was mistaken, Chrome doesn't seem to want to remember ANY fields on this particular site.  Firefox has no trouble remembering any text fields in the exact same form.  This is in SugarCRM (web-based CRM system), so I can't really post a link.  This is the code for the original input box in question though:

```
<input type='text' name='ranumber_c' 
id='ranumber_c' size='30' 
maxlength='255' 
value='300149' title='' tabindex='243' >
```

Are there any other locations in code that would potentially disable (or break) saving form history?

---

EDIT 2:  @iglvzx - Interesting, the DOCTYPE is showing XHTML Strict despite nearly all form tags being improperly generated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Would that actually stop Chrome from recognizing an input field?

Comment: In my experience this issue is caused by web developers not using standard input fields or forcing a field to not be remembered (as with credit card or sensitive info). If you could post some example links, we can look at the HTML source and see what's going on.

Comment: As addon to **iglvzx** words, if possible share screenshots which may help better to understand the issue.

Comment: @Brett, what is the page's [DOCTYPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration)? The input tag should be closed, i.e. `<input ... />`.

Comment: I had that problem at https://catalog.sjlibrary.org/patroninfo/ on the Barcode/ID field. Chrome actually remembers the "Your Name" input, but not "Barcode". Checked in Firefox, and it does properly remember the "Barcode" field.

Comment: If the `value="300149"`, then it should fill out this in the input box, not autocomplete to another value.

Comment: Each browser has its own autocomplete settings.  Is your "Enable Autocomplete" checked in the chrome://settings/  ?

Comment: try this in your html
<input """""" autocomplete ="on">

Comment: there are a few solutions available here, hope one of them can help you:
https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-google-search-autocomplete-not-working-chrome/#:~:text=Step%201%3A%20Open%20Chrome%20on,to%20Autocomplete%20searches%20and%20URLs.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding goes, Firefox will save information for any form input field that has a "name" attribute which the information can be associated to, and chrome/safari/opera only saves specific valuable information such as addresses and payment information.

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing the HTML of the problematic field to others in the same form. What are the similarities? What are the differences?

Without knowing more details though, a more general approach is to force the field to be  categorized by Chrome's Autofill engine. Some fields are not labelled correctly, so Autofill can have trouble with these. As a possible solution, you can allow Chrome to add a unique identifying signature to every form field on the page.

To enable this experimental feature, visit the following URL in a new tab, and then set the flag to **Enabled**:

`chrome://flags/#enable-show-autofill-signatures`

You may also have success with related flags -- visit `chrome://flags` and search for **Autofill** to try some others.

Answer (score 0):

XHTML requires you to close single tags like this:

```
<tag />
```

And also, **you cannot use single quotes.**
so you have to put:

```html
<input type="text" name="ranumber_c" 
id="ranumber_c" size="30"
 maxlength="255" 
value="300149" title="" tabindex="243" />
```